# How to find Row difference based on conditions applied on a different column

Tags: sql

I have a dataset containing name, date and a flag, which is positive, negative, or neutral. The data set is sorted by name and then date. I have to find the difference between the dates of a negative and positive flag, strictly in that order, and the first time this happens for each person. For example if the dataset looks like

```
Aaron     5th Feb.       +
Aaron.    7th Feb.       -
Aaron.    10th Feb.      -
Aaron.    11th Feb.      +
Aaron.    15th. Feb.     -
Aaron.    20th Feb.      +
```

Here, the answer should be 1 day,(between 10th and 11th). So the query should return

```
Aaron.  1
Dave.   2
....    And so on
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server? Please remove the un-necessary tag.

Comment: There is no Dave in your sample dataset. Please provide a desired result according to your actual sample.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this with a MySQL Function:

Here's the sample table:

```
select * from tets;
+-------+---------------------+------+
| name  | date                | flag |
+-------+---------------------+------+
| aron  | 2019-02-05 00:00:00 | +    |
| aron  | 2019-02-07 00:00:00 | -    |
| aron  | 2019-02-10 00:00:00 | -    |
| aron  | 2019-02-11 00:00:00 | +    |
| aron  | 2019-02-15 00:00:00 | -    |
| aron  | 2019-02-20 00:00:00 | +    |
| dave  | 2019-02-04 00:00:00 | +    |
| dave  | 2019-02-06 00:00:00 | -    |
| dave  | 2019-02-08 00:00:00 | -    |
| dave  | 2019-02-10 00:00:00 | +    |
| dave  | 2019-02-11 00:00:00 | -    |
| dave  | 2019-02-12 00:00:00 | +    |
| rambo | 2019-01-06 00:00:00 | -    |
| rambo | 2019-01-08 00:00:00 | +    |
+-------+---------------------+------+
```

If I understand the request correctly, for each of the names above, you want to find the difference between the dates when it changes from "-" to "+" for the first time [We need to strictly consider "-" to "+" and not the other way]

So, a function like below should give you the result: (Forgive the random names for the variables :) )

```
delimiter ||
create  function dummy ()
returns text
begin
declare end_cursor int default 0;
declare i varchar(50);
declare b datetime;
declare c datetime;
declare d datetime;
declare e datetime;
declare ans int(11);
declare prt text default '';

DECLARE a cursor for select distinct(name) from tets;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND set end_cursor=1;

open a;

read_loop: loop 
fetch a into i;
if end_cursor=1
then
LEAVE read_loop;
end if;

set b = (select min(`date`) from tets where name=i and flag='-');
set c = (select min(`date`) from tets where name=i and flag='+');

while b > c
do
set d = (select min(`date`) from tets where name=i and flag='+' and `date`!=c);
set c=d;

end while;

if exists (select `date` from tets where `date` > b and `date` < c)
then
set e = (select max(`date`) from tets where `date` > b and `date` < c);
set b = e;

set ans = datediff(c,b);

set prt = concat( prt,'For ',i,' the dates are ',b,' & ',c,' and the difference is ',ans,', ','\n');

else

set ans = datediff(c,b);

set prt = concat( prt,'For ',i,' the date are ',b,' & ',c,' and the difference is ',ans,', ','\n');

end if;

end loop read_loop;
close a;
return prt;
end;
||
delimiter ;
```

And when I call the Function:

```
mysql> select dummy() \G

dummy(): For aron the dates are 2019-02-10 00:00:00 & 2019-02-11 00:00:00 and         
the difference is 1, 
For dave the dates are 2019-02-08 00:00:00 & 2019-02-10 00:00:00 and the     
difference is 2, 
For rambo the date are 2019-01-06 00:00:00 & 2019-01-08 00:00:00 and the 
difference is 2,
```